# How to pass a promise as a parameter

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-promise

I want to pass a promise as a parameter to another function, use it as a callback.
The code I have works as follows

```
Component 1
function1() {
    let promise: Promise<any>;
    this.function2(promise);
    promise.then(response => console.log(response));
}

Component 2
function2(promise) {
    // Some Code 
    this.dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
       promise.resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Doing it this way produces an error in function 1, the error is: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: What error? ?????

Comment: A promise does not have a public method `.resolve()` so `promise.resolve()` is not appropriate and will be an error.  There's likely a better way to code what you're doing, but you'd have to describe what the goal of `function1()` and `function2()` are and what they should each return (neither of them returns anything).

Comment: I update the answer, 
I want to receive a value in function1 when an asynchronous function (dialogClose) ends in function 2 @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you want to do is something like:

```js
function1() {
  const promise: Promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.function2(resolve);
  });

  promise.then(response => console.log(response));
}

function2(resolveFn: any) {
    // Some Code 
    this.dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
       resolveFn(data);
    });
}
```

**[UPDATE]:** IMO, you should be doing it entirely with observables (no need for promises here):

```js
function1() {
  const afterClosed$: Observable<any> = this.function2();
  afterClosed$.subscribe((response: any) => console.log(response));
}

function2(): Observable<any> {
  // Some Code 
  return this.dialog.afterClosed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer has worked, is there another recommendation on how to do it more efficiently? The case is clear, I need to know when an asynchronous function ends

Comment: Yeah, I've just updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: I cannot convert method 2 into a function because it is used by other functions, in fact I made the parameter resolveFn optional (resolveFn = undefined), for only return the resolve when exists, if you want to make another welcome contribution, thank you very much